# How to remove duplicate photos in Google Photo

Tags: google-plus-photos, google-photos

I used to sync my photos to Drive as well as to Google+.

Now that the two have been merged, I see lots and lots of duplicates in the new Google Photo app.

Unfortunately some of the photos were Drive only while others were in Google+ only and yet others in both...

Short of going through all 16k++ photos in the new app what are my options?

I know that I could use Picasa, but again I'll have to download all pictures first.

Comment: No method is posted till now in the google product forum [post](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/picasa/5GPibPnIcUY)